# Integrate ZXing QR code scanner without installing BarCode Scanner

Tags: android, android-manifest, qr-code, android-library

I am trying to Integrate ZXing QR Code into my android app without installing BarCode Scanner app, I have followed the steps as:

1) Firstly I have downloaded ZXing.zip file and extract it

2)open the ZXing project as an android existing project and then go to android folder and open the android folder and also include core.jar file into the ZXing project named CaptureActivity.

3)I have used the CaptureActivity project as a library in my project named 'QRCodeSample'.
(Problem in including CaptureActivity as a library)

4)My code is as below3:

```
   public class QRCodeSampleActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;
static String contents;

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE",
                    "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);*/
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i("Barcode Result", contents);
            Intent i1 = new Intent(QRCodeSampleActivity.this, webclass.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
            Log.i("Barcode Result","Result canceled");
        }
    }
}

 }
```

The manifest file is :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".QRCodeSampleActivity" >
       <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity  android:name=".webclass"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

and its not adding library also

[image: LibraryInformation]

When I am trying to run my project,the error msg is:

Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.qr.code/com.qr.code}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qr.code in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.qr.code-1.apk]

Comment: To include ZXing is possible I made it. I think you use some other classes. I cannot remember that zxing uses the namespace com.qr.code

Comment: Why are you using library project. You can build the downloaded zxing library to a jar file using ant and include that jar file into your project. Here is the link for the instructions http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Are you sure that this works for Android too? I made my own lib with some custom extensions.

Comment: @blessenm: When I had extracted the ZXing file, then I converted the core folder into it as core.jar file and add it to my project

Comment: you have put the project and the library at the same disk partition

Comment: I have answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822289/3470479

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I got the answer,

**As of ADT 14,the resource fields(such as R.id.decode) are no longer constants when defined in library projects**

So in the ZXing library->android->com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivityHandler.java and DecodeHandler.java

Replace both of these classes switch case statements with if-else,and then import this ZXing library into your project..

Rest of the coding of my own project is same...just the problem with the library classes as these are not updated as according to ADT 14..

Kanika

Comment: Please do not integrate our code as a library project. Please write your own scanner app and reuse pieces if you need to. We did not open source it for you to clone this way.

Comment: I made everything as featured but still got that exception. Why I cant reach those classes? I added it as a lib and also added core.jar as external jar. AndroidRuntime(6316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sonqr/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity

Answer (score 17):

**For all those Android Studio/Gradle users out there**

Okay guys, as my task today was to integrate ZXING into an Android application and there were no good sources for input all over, I will give you a hint what made my be successful - **cause it turned out to be very easy** (on version 2.*).

There is a real handy git repository that provides the zxing android library project as an AAR archive.

- https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal

All you have to do is add this to your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
}
```

and Gradle does all the magic to compile the code and makes it accessible in your app.

To start the Scanner afterwards, use this class/method:

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);    // `this` is the current Activity
```

If you already visited the link you gonna see that i just copy&pasted the code from there the git readme. If not go there to get some more insight and code examples!

Hope to be helpful for future readers. Peace :)

Comment: This looks to me like it's only really useful for barcodes. I need to use it QR codes. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, I downloaded sources from the link You provided. Is it possible to compile it to jar file and then import it to my android studio project? If yes, can You provide some link/instructions on how to build it? I would be most happy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey greenskin, at the github page of xzing there is some more input (first section) https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing

Comment: @LangustenGustel I have one question. I integrated zxing like you said. I need to customize the camera preview? As in add a button to turn on/off the flashlight and a toolbar at the top? Is it possible to do this when you start it via an Intent?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem and after hours struggling with it I finally managed to solve it like this. as Rubiraj is pointing

****Right Click on your project > Properties > Android > (under tab library) Add the Zxing project ****

Assuming you were able to correctly create Zxing project as a Library as it is explained here :
http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Answer (score 3):

**You need to follow step as given by the link**

http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration

**you can download core.jar  from**

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.2/

The above is working for me, if your program still just put the core-2.2.jar in libs and clean your project

Comment: is this a standard fix? You have posted the same answer to several questions

Comment: It long time I have posted this but see this link if it help http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/06/integrating-zxing-qr-code-scanner-into.html  Let me know so that I will update my comment

Answer (score 2):

MaterialBarcodeScanner: Easy to use barcode reader for your Android Project (Uses Google Mobile Vision API).

1. Provide gradle dependency

   compile 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'
2. Build a MaterialBarcodeScanner

   ```
   private void startScan() {
       /**
        * Build a new MaterialBarcodeScanner
        */
       final MaterialBarcodeScanner mBarcodeScanner 
                = new MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder()
               .withActivity(MainActivity.this)
               .withEnableAutoFocus(true)
               .withBleepEnabled(true)
               .withBackfacingCamera()
               .withText("Scanning...")
               .withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
                       barcodeResult = barcode;
                       result.setText(barcode.rawValue);
                   }
               })
               .build();
       mBarcodeScanner.startScan();
   }
   ```
3. Hook it up to a button

   ```
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    startScan();
   }
   });
   ```
4. Start scanning!

Comment: How can I use this library for continuous scanning (e.g.: without having to touch the button)?

Answer (score 1):

**Step by step to setup zxing 3.2.1 in eclipse**

1. Download zxing-master.zip from "https://github.com/zxing/zxing"
2. Unzip zxing-master.zip, Use eclipse to import "android" project in zxing-master
3. Download core-3.2.1.jar from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.1/"
4. Create "libs" folder in "android" project and paste cor-3.2.1.jar into the libs folder
5. Click on project: choose "properties" -> "Java Compiler" to change level to 1.7. Then click on "Android" change "Project build target" to android 4.4.2+, because using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4
6. If "CameraConfigurationUtils.java" don't exist in "zxing-master/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/". You can copy it from "zxing-master/android-core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/" and paste to your project.
7. Clean and build project. If your project show error about "switch - case", you should change them to "if - else".
8. Completed. Clean and build project. You can click on "Proprties" > "Android" > click on "Is Libraries" to use for your project

Answer (score 0):

1. After importing Zxing as existing project, Properties > Java Buildpath > Check "is library" (check button) and then try to add Zxing as library.
2. Make sure `webclass.class` exist in your `QRcodesampleActivity.java`