# How can I implement a QR code reader in my android app without using phonegap?

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I want to implement a QR scanner with my android application but I am not getting any perfect solution
I want to have a inbuilt Scanner without using ZXing or phonegap.

Comment: Huh? Either you have software in app to decode or send it off to a server. Try explaining your problem in more detail.

Comment: [Have you seen this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8340875/940096)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ZXing as a internal library instead of requiring the user to have barcode scanner installer.

Actually you can use the Barcode Scanner source code:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

Comment: I will mention that members of the ZXing team have specifically stated on a few occasions that they don't particularly like this approach, though it is still certainly possible to do. http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/#comment-159

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest way to integrate barcode scanning on Android is this:
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

It does not involve PhoneGap, or even much code.

Comment: i use this one too, its really good :D

Comment: but ZXing requires barcode scanner app to be already installed in your device else it asks to install the app

Comment: ...making it impossible to read a QR code without internet connection if you have not previously downloaded Barcode Scanner