# ClassNotFoundException while Detecting ZXing BarCode scanner in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am using the below lines for detecting the **ZXing Barcode scanner**,but it is raising Exception called `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
try{
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
 //calling Alert message which says to download the application
}
```

`ClassNotFoundException` saying  `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity` is not found.But I didnt understand why this exception is not handled eventhough I put this in try,catch Blocks.

complete code:

I also tried by using  isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) method,but still I am getting same error.

```
 try{
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");


      if(isIntentAvailable(this,  intent)){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        pd.dismiss();
        }
        });

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        else{
         AlertDialog diaBox = installDialogBox();

         diaBox.show();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        pd.dismiss();
        Log.e("in Exception","Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

method: to check whether application is installed or not.

```
 public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
final PackageManager packageManager =  context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list =packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

return list.size() > 0;
            }
```

Logcat Error:

```
05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zzzzz.xxxxx.activies/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sparx.maternity.activies-2.apk]
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.sparx.maternity.activies-2.apk]
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
    05-24 10:24:36.507: E/AndroidRuntime(9159):     ... 11 more
```

Please reply.

Comment: add ： catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { }
and see the result。

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Its the worst answer dude. What are you thinking ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if intent is available before calling it

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
      List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Also try using

```
 try {
          ....
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO handle me
        }
```

Comment: if I used the above code,my app gets crashed saying the above error if the application is not installed in my device.If the application is installed in my device its working fine.

Comment: I didnt understand why cant I handle the exception

Comment: The exception is `ClassNotFoundException`, not `ActivityNotFoundException`. This is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is need to inquire whether it has this app. and it is not to catching an Exception

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
```

list.size() > 0 , It mean that there is the target application.

Comment: The exception is `ClassNotFoundException`, not `ActivityNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating by `Intent`. But I'm going to guess that you have also tried to include our code, and parts of our manifest, in your project. Don't do this. It's not necessary, and causes errors like this, because you are also telling Android that the code is in your app. It's not, and should not be.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in many ways in SO. Zxing can be a pain to integrate sometimes. Follow the older posts that have helped others, redo your integration, you have missed some steps I am sure.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340875/integrate-zxing-qr-code-scanner-without-installing-barcode-scanner)